# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' cant get it

Tags: python, pandas

```
n = 5 df10_1920 = df10[(df10.year > 1920) & (df10.year < 1940)].sample(n)
      df10_1960 = df10[(df10.year > 1960) & (df10.year < 1980)].sample(n)
      df10_2000 = df10[df10.year > 2000].sample(n)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

what do I have to change?

this is the data

```
trailer_title   url imdb_id year    rating  votes   genre
0   THE BIG PARADE trailer  https://archive.org/download/TheBigParadeTrail...   15624   1925    7.9 6148.0  Drama|Romance|War
1   ALL QUIET ON THE WESTERN FRONT 1930 trailer https://archive.org/download/AllQuietOnTheWest...   20629   1930    8.0 56948.0 Drama|War
2   THE OREGON TRAIL trailer    https://archive.org/download/TheOregonTrailTra...   20691   1926    7.2 3353.0  Adventure|Romance|Western
3   FIVE STAR FINAL trailer https://archive.org/download/FiveStarFinalTrai...   21873   1931    7.2 1790.0  Crime|Drama
4   LITTLE CAESAR trailer   https://archive.org/download/LittleCaesarTrail...   21079   1931    7.3 11958.0 Action|Crime|Drama|Romance
```

Comment: that means your `df10.year` is holding string value. you need to type cast it to `int` (if your string is holding numeric value) to make your logic work

Comment: df10['year'].astype(int)

Comment: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: try to filter out 'nan' ,'' or whichever string that can't be casted to integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pandas' `.loc` method.Here is the code:

```
year = df['year']
df10_1920 = df.loc[(year > 1920) & (year < 1940)]
df10_1960 = df.loc[(year > 1960) & (year < 1980)]
df10_2000 = df.loc[year >2000]
```

Comment: Then i get the following error ,  TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: I would need to see a sample of your data

Comment: please can you tell me how?

Comment: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: If this is your data, please add it to your question. Thanks!

Comment: I can't copy and paste this data. Do you have a link to where you got the data from?

Comment: If you have a csv, open it in notepad, or something similar, and then copy and paste it from there

Comment: is there someone who can help me?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'year'    I get know this error

Comment: @O.N.J.RP Updated. I tested it, and it should work!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!